# UITextView cuts off text on iPhone 5/5s but not in iPhone 6

Tags: ios, swift, formatting, uitextview, nsattributedstring

I am resizing a UITextView for an attributed string that I create based on a response from my API that can have up to three different attributes; general terms, shipping terms, and return terms. If one of the attributes is missing, I don't show that attribute in the final text. On the iPhone 6, everything shows up exactly the way it should, but on the iPhone 5/5s, the last few lines of text get cutt off. The textView is resizing properly, but it doesn't show all of the text up until the last few lines. I wish I could show photos, but apparently I don't have enough rep to do so. Every other similar issue that I've searched isn't quite the same, and none of those solutions seem to fix the problem. Here is my code, in Swift, for creating the attributed string and resizing the textView. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

This is the code for formatting the attributed string

```
var termStrings = String()

                    if (!generalString.isEqualToString("")) {
                        termStrings += "GENERAL:\n\(generalString)\n\n"
                    }

                    if (!shippingString.isEqualToString("")) {
                        termStrings += "SHIPPING:\n\(shippingString)\n\n"
                    }

                    if (!returnString.isEqualToString("")) {
                        termStrings += "RETURNS:\n\(returnString)"
                    }

                    var newNSString = termStrings as NSString

                    var attTermString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: termStrings as String)

                    let boldAttribute = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.blackColor(), NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(14)]
                    let subtitleAttribute = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.blackColor(), NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(12)]
                    let underlineAttribute = [NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName: NSUnderlineStyle.StyleSingle]
                    var paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
                    paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = 5.0

                    if (!generalString.isEqualToString("")) {
                        attTermString.addAttributes(boldAttribute, range: newNSString.rangeOfString("GENERAL:"))
                        attTermString.addAttribute(NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName, value: NSUnderlineStyle.StyleSingle.rawValue, range: newNSString.rangeOfString("GENERAL:"))
                        attTermString.addAttribute(NSParagraphStyleAttributeName, value: paragraphStyle, range: newNSString.rangeOfString("GENERAL:\n"))
                        attTermString.addAttributes(subtitleAttribute, range: newNSString.rangeOfString("\(generalString)"))
                    }

                    if (!shippingString.isEqualToString("")) {
                        attTermString.addAttributes(boldAttribute, range: newNSString.rangeOfString("SHIPPING:"))
                        attTermString.addAttribute(NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName, value: NSUnderlineStyle.StyleSingle.rawValue, range: newNSString.rangeOfString("SHIPPING:"))
                        attTermString.addAttribute(NSParagraphStyleAttributeName, value: paragraphStyle, range: newNSString.rangeOfString("SHIPPING:\n"))
                        attTermString.addAttributes(subtitleAttribute, range: newNSString.rangeOfString("\(shippingString)"))
                    }

                    if (!returnString.isEqualToString("")) {
                        attTermString.addAttributes(boldAttribute, range: newNSString.rangeOfString("RETURNS:"))
                        attTermString.addAttribute(NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName, value: NSUnderlineStyle.StyleSingle.rawValue, range: newNSString.rangeOfString("RETURNS:"))
                        attTermString.addAttribute(NSParagraphStyleAttributeName, value: paragraphStyle, range: newNSString.rangeOfString("RETURNS:\n"))
                        attTermString.addAttributes(subtitleAttribute, range: newNSString.rangeOfString("\(returnString)"))
                    }

                    changeTextViewHeight(attTermString, width: textView.frame.size.width)
```

This is my code for resizing the textView

```
func changeTextViewHeight(attributedString: NSMutableAttributedString, width: CGFloat) {
    textView.attributedText = attributedString
    var newSize: CGSize  = textView.sizeThatFits(CGSizeMake(width, CGFloat(FLT_MAX)))
    var newFrame: CGRect = textView.frame
    newFrame.size = CGSizeMake(CGFloat(fmaxf((Float)(newSize.width), (Float)(width))), newSize.height)
    textView.frame = newFrame
}
```

Comment: As per my assumption you may passed wrong `Width` for iPhone5/5s, or you have designed your screen for iPhone 6. so just debug the width you pass in resizing the textView, and you will get your solution.

Comment: I will give that a shot, but the text isn't going off the screen or anything, which leads me to believe everything is sizing properly. I will log the width though. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Steps to resolve (**This will set the UITextView scroll to the top in 5/5s**)

- Disable the UITextView scroll view
- set scrollRectToVisible Enable
- UITextView scroll

Swift 3:

```
self.yourTextView.isScrollEnabled = false
let rect:CGRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1, height: 1)
self.yourTextView.scrollRectToVisible(rect, animated: false)
self.yourTextView.isScrollEnabled = true
```

This Worked for me.